# Does sudo documentedly handles characters after backslash on all UNIX-like systems? - for breaking long lines

Tags: sudo

In general, you can put a "\" at the end of your long command/line to break it to several lines.

The sudoers syntax allows this too, that's OK.

But:

If there is an ex.: "space" after the "\" character, a command/script would break, **but sudo doesn't**.

**Question**: Is it official (and where is it documented) that sudo accepts spaces after "\" on all UNIX-like systems?

Example for commands:

Normal backslashing:

```
$ echo a; \
> echo b
a
b
```

A space was put after backslash:

```
$ echo a; \ 
a
bash:  : command not found
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior depends on context because the `\` is handled by different applications.

The sudoers file is a configuration file from `sudo` and therefore handled by a parser in `sudo`. So it depends on the implementation of `sudo`, which *may* vary from system to system. E.g. from `man sudoers` on OSX:

> Long lines can be continued with a backslash ('\') as the last
>   **character** on the line.

The other behavior you describe is handled by `bash` and documented in `man bash`:

> If a `\<newline>` pair  appears,  and  the  backslash  is  not  itself
>          quoted,  the  `\<newline>`  is  treated  as a line continuation (that is, it is removed from the input stream and
>          effectively ignored).

Other shells may have different implementations.

Comment: documentation says '\' supposed to be the last character, but in reality it handles space after it, OK. Thanks!